# Yii logout not working after enable memcache

Tags: yii, memcached

I'm trying to enable memcache for PHP sessions in my Yii application, but after enabling this memcache , yii logout is not working.

```
/**
     * Logs out the current user and redirect to homepage.
     */
    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::app()->user->logout();
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->homeUrl);
    }
```

Please can anyone help me by your valuable suggestions !!!

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "*is not working*"? Is there an error?  Is there something in the logs (`runtime/logs/app.log`)?

Comment: No error in log, sometimes logout is working , sometimes its just refresh the page logout not working